# C++: Drawing a 2D disk in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I've tried to write a proper function for drawing a 2D disk on the screen with OpenGL for a few days now, and I simply can't seem to get it right :(

This is my current code:

```
void Disk( Float x, Float y, Float r, const Color& vColor )
{
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );
        glVertex2f( x, y );
        for( Float i = 0; i <= 2 * PI + 0.1; i += 0.1 )
        {
            glVertex2f( x + sin( i ) * r, y + cos( i ) * r );
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

When zooming in, the resulting disk shows spikes, not as in edges but really spikes pointing out.

Also the function doesn't draw one disk only, but always a bit more than one - which means that if alpha is enabled, the results look wrong.

- What do I need to change in my function so it properly draws a disk?

Answer (score 12):

```
void circle(float x, float y, float r, int segments)
{
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        for( int n = 0; n <= segments; ++n ) {
            float const t = 2 * M_PI * (float)n / (float)segments;
            glVertex2f(x + sin(t) * r, y + cos(t) * r);
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

that should get you rid of the overdraw. About the spikes... a picture could tell a thousand words.

Comment: Consider using `GL_LINE_LOOP` in your begin call and this will do it for him I think.

Comment: your version will underdraw and leave the last triangle empty. Between the end of the for loop and the glEnd() another vertex is needed that duplicates the first in the loop.  glVertex2f( x , y + r );

Comment: @Mark Thalman: Not quite, note that the for loop goes t to 1.0 inclusive, so this does exactly duplicate the last vertex. But the better solution would be incrementing a int with the range end inclusive.

Comment: When I ran the previous version of the code it had the problem I mentioned. Floats can be fickel things, so my compiler/os may have been exiting earlier than you intended.

Comment: +1 for integer loops: loops with floating point end conditions are a recipe for trouble.  For consistency with polar coordinates, I might change the order of your sin and cos.  As to the OP's spikes: perhaps he's got special versions/macros of sin and cos that take arguments in degrees?