# OpenGL+GLUT Not filling Topmost-Leftmost Polygon?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm encountering a strange OpenGL Bug.  OpenGL is pretty new to me, but we're required to use it in my AI class (because the teacher is really a Graphics professor).

Either way, this is happening: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/422/reversiothello.png

It happens to only the topmost, leftmost polygon. In other words, it finds the furthest polygon left, and then the furthest up and it does that to it.  (There is not currently anything erasing polygons from the board).

My display function is this:

```
void display_func(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.45, 0.0, 1.0); // Background Color (Forest Green :3)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    draw_board();

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();
};
```

My draw_board function is this:

```
void draw_board()
{
    int size = 8;
    int stepX = WINDOW_XS / size;
    int stepY = WINDOW_YS / size;

    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); // line color black

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    // Draw Columns
    for(int i = 0;i <= WINDOW_XS;i += stepX)
    {
        glVertex2i(i,0);
        glVertex2i(i, WINDOW_YS);
    }

    // Draw Rows
    for(int j = 0;j <= WINDOW_YS;j += stepY)
    {
        glVertex2i(0, j);
        glVertex2i(WINDOW_XS, j);
    }

    // Draw Circles
    for(int i = 0;i < 8;++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < 8;++j)
        {
            if(engine->getOnBoard(i,j) == Reversi::PIECE_NONE) continue;
            if(engine->getOnBoard(i,j) == Reversi::PIECE_WHITE)
                glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
            if(engine->getOnBoard(i,j) == Reversi::PIECE_BLACK)
                glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);

            int drawX = ((i+1)*64)-32;
            int drawY = 512-((j+1)*64)+32;
            gl_drawCircle(drawX,drawY,30);
        }
    }

    glEnd();
};
```

My mouse function is this:

```
void mouse_func(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN && x < WINDOW_XS)
    {    
        // row and column index
        x = (int)( x / (WINDOW_XS/8) );
        y = (int)( y / (WINDOW_YS/8) );

        std::cout << "Attempting to make a move at " << x << "," << y << std::endl;

        if(engine->makeMove(x,y))
        {
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
};
```

and my gl_drawCircle function is this:

```
void gl_drawCircle(float x, float y, float r)
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094992/c-drawing-a-2d-circle-in-opengl/5095188#5095188
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
    float t;
    int n;
    for(t = 0,n = 0; n <= 90; ++n, t = float(n)/90.f ) // increment by a fraction of the maximum 
    {
        glVertex2f( x + sin( t * 2 * PI ) * r, y + cos( t * 2 * PI ) * r );
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: not done opengl in a while, could it be that in your `draw_board` function the `glEnd();` has to come before the `draw circles`for statements, otherwise you have a `glBegin` within another `glBegin` which i don't think is allowed.

Comment: SwapBuffers implicitly directs the OpenGL calls to the correct buffer, there's no need to call glFlush first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only bug worth giving an answer that I can find is that your `draw_board` function doesn't use properly the `glBegin` and `glEnd` statements. You have to use a `glEnd` statement before calling `gl_drawCircle`, otherwise you'll get a nasty behavior.

Edit: you first circle is drawn using lines because the `glBegin` is ignored (since you are in a `glBegin` context). All other circles are done ok because you do a `glEnd` before calling `glBegin` again. The first drawn circle is the leftmost, topmost circle.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Its easy to miss little things when you're new to something.

Answer (score 3):

You need a call to glEnd after drawing the rows.
When you do not call glEnd, OpenGL ignores your call `glBegin( GL_POLYGON );` and assumes you still want to draw lines.

So just adding
`glEnd ();`
after drawing the rows should solve it.